# Firebase cloud storage security rules and Firebase database connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to add firebase cloud storage security rules so that my file can be access by set of people's. List of people's are in my firebase database.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the Firebase Database from your Cloud Storage for Firebase security rules. You will have to set the information into the token for each user, and then access *that* in your storage rules.

Also see:

- [Restrict firebase database and storage write access to a specific group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49196390/restrict-firebase-database-and-storage-write-access-to-a-specific-group)
- [is there a way to authenticate user role in firebase storage rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187424/is-there-a-way-to-authenticate-user-role-in-firebase-storage-rules)
- [Create group access to firebase storage without using custom authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188459/create-group-access-to-firebase-storage-without-using-custom-authorization)

Some of these show embedding the UIDs in the security rules, which used to be the only way to do this. But nowadays you should probably user custom claims for this, as shown in Bojeil's answer to the first question above.