# Use firebase Authentication with role users

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to use firebase Authentication (sign in with email) and an user roles management ?
I'm using ionic and would like to login to the app with some users who have different roles.
I would like to use the Firebase Firestore to store other data.

What is the best solution to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using custom claims: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878040/how-do-i-set-up-roles-in-firebase-auth

Answer (score 0):

Well, I actually hoped that there was a feature like this too but as far as I know, there isn't as at the moment.
What can be done though is ask a user to choose his/her role while registering/signing up, and then this role gets stored with the user's other details that may be needed; then when this user wants to login, your application checks if the user is a registered user and then checks the database for the user's details (the role inclusive) and then the app works with the user based on this role.
Not a very good implementation but the closest I can proffer because this is the method I use

You can check out this question too [how do I implement role based access control in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520615/how-do-i-implement-role-based-access-control-in-firebase)