# How to secure firebase using roles, when making connections directly from client

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, mobile, firebase-security

We get this warning:

```
[Firebase] Your Realtime Database has insecure rules

    We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
any logged-in user can read your entire database
any logged-in user can write to your entire database
Without strong security rules, anyone who has the address of your 
database can read / write to it, leaving your data vulnerable to attackers
stealing, modifying, or deleting data as well as creating costly operations.
```

we could give different users different roles, **but** since the connection is made directly through our client app, what's stopping anyone from changing their role/token etc? How can it ultimately be made more secure?

Comment: note relevant security procedures? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36878040/how-do-i-set-up-roles-in-firebase-auth/46457309#46457309